# Moving a mount point to a new device

Tags: linux, rhel

We have a server that we setup to host an application. Our vendor configured it, but now, they are saying that one of the partitions is too small and we need more space.

[image]

Basically the /u01 partition is 98% full. We added some space and I mounted it on /mnt/esmdata because initially my thought was to do a symlink on the folder that is the culprit for size.

However, our vendor said that symlinks will not work so now I'm not sure how to get the space on /mnt/esmupgdata onto /u01

Do I use mount --move? is it possible to copy all the contents to /mnt/esmupgdata the mount that /dev/sdb onto /u01?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WARNING:** This looks like to be a database (ORACLE?), you are about to do potentially destructive things

If **this is a database** (is this u01 Oracle?), please BACKUP and **STOP, really stop it first with shutdown immediate** (for Oracle for example)...

Then, cp -a /u01/* /mnt/esmupgdata/

This must copy your data respecting the permissions symlinks and more that your database use.

Then edit your /etc/fstab (backup it first) and you will probably see something like this:

```
/dev/sda3 /u01 #a lot of stranger things that your grandmother don't like
/dev/sdb /mnt/esmupgdata #a lot of stranger things that your grandmother don't like
```

Just change it to:

```
/dev/sdb /u01 #a lot of stranger things that your grandmother don't like
/dev/sda3 /mnt/esmupgdata #a lot of stranger things that your grandmother don't like
```

If you are not mounting it by fstab, what are you doing? just remount all in the corrected order...

With FSTAB:

```
umount /dev/sdb
umount /dev/sda3

mount /u01 
mount /mnt/esmupgdata
```

Now esmupgdata will have the old partition and u01 the new

Comment: First, thank you so much for the reply. I truly appreciate it. As far as I know this isn't a database, more like a place that an application stores upgrade files (the application doesn't allow deleting so it will just keep growing in size). I'm pretty sure.  I will try that and report. Thank you again

Comment: It worked! thank you so much :) so much appreciated